# How map a biginit inside entity framework, and how to convert a string into biginit

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a field named assetid inside sql server with type Biginit.so how I can map this field inside entity framework, and convert a string to biginit.
The biginit will be received as an XML string value such as:-

```
<operation> 
<operationstatus>Success</operationstatus> 
<resourcename>serverrr090909</resourcename> 
<assetid>2701</assetid> 
<message>Rack serverrr090909 added successfully</message> 
</operation>
```

So I am trying to write something such as :-

```
Var assetid =  message = doc.SelectSingleNode("/operation/message").InnerText;
// so how I can convert the string into biginit
```

**update**

I wrote the following :-

```
    public void InsertOrUpdateRack(Rack rack,string username,long assetid)
            {       
//code goes here
    IT360ID = assetid,
                        }
```

but it raised the folloiwng error on `IT360ID = assetid`,Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). so how i can assign an int? field a long value?

Comment: What number do you expect "Rack serverrr090909 added successfully" to convert into?

Comment: no i need to convert the assetid which is returned as an xml string , into biginit .

Comment: `biginit`? do you mean `bigint`?

Comment: yes bigint. As the assetid inside the SQL server is defined as bigint, But i will receive it as a XML string , but i need to convert the XML string to bigint , or the best datatype inside entity framework that can hold bigint values.

Answer (score 6):

Just use a `long` (same as `Int64`):

```
long assetid = long.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("/operation/assetid").InnerText);
```

Comment: is it risky to convert Bigint to long inside entity framewrok ?

Comment: No, both are 64-bit integers.

Comment: Yeap, my bad, worked to much today. (( But it's not a problem, today is a friday, and the bottle of cold beer is already waiting for me!

Comment: @DStanley can you check my Update, please/

Comment: @Asp.netmvcAsp.netmvc did you specify the type in the model or did EF generate it from the database?  If the type is a nullable `bigint` it should have created a `long?` field instead of an `int?` field.